# What stops telomerase?

Tags: enzymes, telomere, protein-binding

The telomerase is an enzyme that adds telomeres.

What stops the telomerase from adding too many telomere sequences ? What's the regulating mechanism ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Telomerases are tightly controlled on all level: Expression, post-translational modifications and by external factors. I think for this the external factors, a protein class called telomeric proteins. They bind to the end of the telomere and regulate the telomerase.

[image]

The figure is from this paper, which looks into the topic quite extensively:

- [Regulation of telomerase by telomeric proteins.](http://delangelab.rockefeller.edu/pubs/78_Smogorzewska_Ann_Rev_Biochem_2004.pdf)